# Combine two table for one output sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables

Threads:

```
i_id thread_note seq_id
 1       ABC        2
 2       CDE        2
 3       FGH        1
 4       IJK        2
```

Notes:

```
i_id  note_text entered_date
 1      stack     09/08/2017
 5      queue     07/07/2014
 3      push      09/07/1996
```

I want the output as

```
i_id  thread_note  seq_id   note_text  entered_date
 1       ABC         2        stack     09/08/2017
 2       CDE         2        null        null
 3       FGH         1        push      09/07/1996
 4       IJK         2        null        null   
 5       null        null     queue     07/07/2014
```

How do I achieve this? The tables are not related to each other.

Note: This is different from most of the questions similar to this asked because there are some "i_id" values which are present in threads table but not in notes table and there are some "i_id" values present in notes table but not in threads table

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592).
Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),
and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Thank you for enlightening me :)
I have tried

SELECT i_id, thread_note, seq_id
FROM threads
UNION ALL
SELECT i_id, note_text, entered_date
FROM notes

It doesn't work.

Can you please give suggestions on how to get the desired result?

Comment: what RDBMS you are using?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention. I am using SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a full outer join:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(t.i_id, n.i_id) AS i_id,
    t.thread_note,
    t.seq_id,
    n.note_text,
    n.entered_date
FROM Threads t
FULL OUTER JOIN Notes n
    ON n.i_id = t.i_id
ORDER BY
    i_id;
```

Note that having the need to do a full outer join often can indicate a problem with your relational model, because it means you don't know the key relationships between your tables.

### Demo

**Edit:**

If you are using a database such as MySQL which does not support a full outer join, we can still simulate one:

```
SELECT *
FROM Threads t
LEFT JOIN Notes n
    ON n.i_id = t.i_id
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM Threads t
RIGHT JOIN Notes n
    ON n.i_id = t.i_id
WHERE t.i_id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to get all `i_id` from all tables in a subquery. Once you have the rows, join this to the two tables to get the columns you need,

```
SELECT  a.i_id,
        b.thread_note,
        b.seq_id,
        c.Note_text,
        c.entered_date
FROM
        (
            SELECT i_id FROM Threads UNION 
            SELECT i_id FROM Notes
        ) a
        LEFT JOIN Threads b
            ON a.i_id = b.i_id
        LEFT JOIN Notes c
            ON a.i_id = c.i_id
ORDER BY a.i_id
```

Here's a [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0604b9/2).

Comment: John, even if the OP is using MySQL, it might be easier to just simulate a full outer join as a union of a left and right join.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a `FULL OUTER JOIN` here.  If I make some test data:

```
DECLARE @threads TABLE (i_id INT, thread_note NVARCHAR(3), seq_id INT);
INSERT INTO @threads SELECT 1, 'ABC', 2;
INSERT INTO @threads SELECT 2, 'CDE', 2;
INSERT INTO @threads SELECT 3, 'FGH', 1;
INSERT INTO @threads SELECT 4, 'IJK', 2;
DECLARE @notes TABLE (i_id INT, note_text NVARCHAR(10), entered_date DATE);
INSERT INTO @notes SELECT 1, 'stack', '20170809';
INSERT INTO @notes SELECT 5, 'queue', '20140707';
INSERT INTO @notes SELECT 3, 'push', '19960709';
```

Then my query is simply:

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(t.i_id, n.i_id) AS i_id,
    t.thread_note,
    t.seq_id,
    n.note_text,
    n.entered_date
FROM
    @threads t
    FULL OUTER JOIN @notes n ON n.i_id = t.i_id
ORDER BY
    ISNULL(t.i_id, n.i_id);
```

No need to make a list of unique I_ids.

Comment: No, it's fine, because we may `ORDER BY` an alias defined in the select clause.

Answer (score -1):

Use the below query

```
select Isnull(n.i_id,t.i_id), [thread_note],seq_id,Notetest,Enddate  
from [dbo].[note] n  FULL OUTER JOIN [dbo].[thread] t on n.[i_id]=t.[i_id]
order by Isnull(n.i_id,t.i_id)
```